# Retrieving User Collection from API / MongoDB but exclude Password Field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, security, express

I am constructing an api which retrieves articles. I also have users in my database, and would like to have one endpoint which returns the user. `/api/users/:userid`. This returns something along these lines:

```
{
"articles": [], //array w. references to articles the user has written
"_id": "5b1321321bcda0e3364251d7e4a", 
"email": "user@email.com",
"password": "$2a$1231241gi14k41k42bk12bh3k127iP/k1LAqwPdbgF/bXXpRia",
"__v": 0
}
```

-- However, I am not sure whether it's a good idea to return the (encrypted) password in the API. Can I somehow exclude this field, or would you recommend to store emails + user_ids in a separate collection on mongodb, or how are things like this usually handled?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Project Fields to Return from Query` to exclude password field from your response.

```
db.users.find( { email: "user@email.com" }, { password: 0} )
```

Comment: are you sure this is correct? I just tried it and it gives me email **and** password *only* - so it doesn't excludes the password, but *everything else* it seems?

Comment: I just looked it up: To exclude is `0`, not a `-1` - so that works! Is this solution recommended as well or are there still security concerns involved?

Comment: yes for excluding any field, correct is `0` instead of `-1`

Answer (score 0):

Alright It is not best practice and advisable to return a user's `password`. What I normally do is use the `lodash` library for operations like this for example, you can have a utility function that omits the password field before your API returns a response like so

`function omitPassword(user) {
  return _.omit(user.toObject(), ['password']);
}`

basically `_.omit` is a method from lodash. I hope this helps what you are looking for.